# Laravel Array to String Conversion Error Exception

Tags: php, laravel

im a beginner in using laravel and while i was making a new controller and run php artisan optimize

this error happened

what do i do?

````
  at F:\capstone\sms-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php:416
    412▕     protected function getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options)
    413▕     {
    414▕         $name = $this->getResourceRouteName($resource, $method, $options);
    415▕
  ➜ 416▕         $action = ['as' => $name, 'uses' => $controller.'@'.$method];
    417▕
    418▕         if (isset($options['middleware'])) {
    419▕             $action['middleware'] = $options['middleware'];
    420▕         }

  1   F:\capstone\sms-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php:416
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}("Array to string conversion", 
"F:\capstone\sms-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php")

  2   F:\capstone\sms-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php:189
      Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar::getResourceAction("dashboard", "index", []) ```
````

Comment: have you made any changes to the route/web.php file??

Comment: show the resource route you defined

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the routes/api.php file
there is a wrong routing
which is not an array but a string

for example:
Route::resource('products', [ProductController::class]);

Becomes:
Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);

careful use syntax  []